# Way in azure pipelines to increment major minor or patch versions based on the source branch

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I'm trying to use azure pipeline to build a tar.gz package on a linux build server.Iis there way in VSTS/Azure Pipeline code to increment default major:minor:patch based on source branch?

Example:

If source branch is Develop: major:minor(increment):patch
If source branch is bugfix: major:minor:patch(increment)
If source branch is main: major(increment):minor:patch

Please let me know your suggestions. Thank you

I'm trying to use azure pipeline to build a tar.gz package on a linux build server.Iis there way in VSTS/Azure Pipeline code to increment default major:minor:patch based on source branch?

Example:

If source branch is Develop: major:minor(increment):patch
If source branch is bugfix: major:minor:patch(increment)
If source branch is main: major(increment):minor:patch

Please let me know your suggestions. Thank you

Comment: Look into using GitVersion.

Comment: DevOps doesn't have built_in feature to achieve this, I write a YAML and it can manage the major, minor, patch. See my answer. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your requirement doesn't have a built in feature.

There is a [counter expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#counter) in DevOps pipeline, it can auto increase a variable for each pipeline run, but this feature will forcibly increased every time the pipeline is run, and cannot be increased or stopped arbitrarily.

> counter expression is for pipeline, and it has two parameters, prefix
> and seed. Seed is based on the prefix.
>
> When the prefix is been set and run for the first time, the counter
> result will start from the feed value. But for the later run based on
> the same prefix, the counter result will ignore the feed value, it
> will be 'last time counter result + 1'

Since the counter expression has such limitation, I Write a more free design for you to manage the major, minor and patch.

The below is the YAML definition of the pipeline.

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
parameters: #The default value of increase major, minor, patch are all false. If you change these to true, the major, minor, patch will auto_increase by default.
- name: increase_major
  default: false
  type: boolean
  values:
    - true
    - false
- name: increase_minor
  default: false
  type: boolean
  values:
    - true
    - false
- name: increase_patch
  default: false
  type: boolean
  values:
    - true
    - false
variables:
- name: Personal_Access_Token
  value: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" #Put your personal Access Token here.

- ${{ if eq(parameters.increase_major,false)}}:
  - name: increase_major
    value: false
- ${{ if eq(parameters.increase_major,true)}}:
  - name: increase_major
    value: true

- ${{ if eq(parameters.increase_minor,false)}}:
  - name: increase_minor
    value: false
- ${{ if eq(parameters.increase_minor,true)}}:
  - name: increase_minor
    value: true

- ${{ if eq(parameters.increase_patch,false)}}:
  - name: increase_patch
    value: false
- ${{ if eq(parameters.increase_patch,true)}}:
  - name: increase_patch
    value: true

steps:

#===============================
#Put your pipeline steps here.
#===============================

# The below code will help you auto increase the major, minor, patch.
- task: PythonScript@0
  displayName: Change the Major, Minor, Patch.
  inputs:
    scriptSource: inline
    script: |
      import json
      import requests

      #This part is defnition of variables

      org_name = "BowmanCP"
      project_name = "BowmanCP"
      pipeline_definition_id = "376"
      personal_access_token = "$(Personal_Access_Token)"

      key = 'variables'

      increase_major_control = '$(increase_major)'
      increase_minor_control = '$(increase_minor)'
      increase_patch_control = '$(increase_patch)'


      major = "major"
      minor = "minor"
      patch = "patch"

      #This part is logic for auto increase major, minor, patch

      def get_value_of_specific_variable(json_content, key, var_name):
          data = json.loads(json_content)
          return data[key][var_name].get('value')

      def auto_increase(json_content, key, var_name):
          data = json.loads(json_content)
          data[key][var_name]['value'] = str(int(get_value_of_specific_variable(json_content,key,var_name)) + 1)
          return data

      def get_pipeline_definition(org_name, project_name, pipeline_definition_id, personal_access_token):
          url = "https://dev.azure.com/"+org_name+"/"+project_name+"/_apis/build/definitions/"+pipeline_definition_id+"?api-version=6.0"

          payload={}
          headers = {
          'Authorization': 'Basic '+personal_access_token
          }

          response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
          json_content = response.text
          return json_content

      def update_pipeline_definition(org_name, project_name, pipeline_definition_id, json_content, key, var_name):
          json_data = auto_increase(json_content, key, var_name)
          url2 = "https://dev.azure.com/"+org_name+"/"+project_name+"/_apis/build/definitions/"+pipeline_definition_id+"?api-version=6.0"

          payload2 = json.dumps(json_data)
          headers2 = {
          'Authorization': 'Basic '+personal_access_token,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }

          response2 = requests.request("PUT", url2, headers=headers2, data=payload2)
      #increase major
      if increase_major_control == 'true':
          json_data = update_pipeline_definition(org_name, project_name, pipeline_definition_id, get_pipeline_definition(org_name, project_name, pipeline_definition_id, personal_access_token), key, major)
      if increase_minor_control == 'true':
          json_data = update_pipeline_definition(org_name, project_name, pipeline_definition_id, get_pipeline_definition(org_name, project_name, pipeline_definition_id, personal_access_token), key, minor)
      if increase_patch_control == 'true':
          json_data = update_pipeline_definition(org_name, project_name, pipeline_definition_id, get_pipeline_definition(org_name, project_name, pipeline_definition_id, personal_access_token), key, patch)
```

When you run it, just click the checkbox will determine whether increase the variable of major, minor and patcH:

[image]

The variables are in this place:

[image]

[image]

## Design Ideas:

Use [Definitions - Get REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0) to get the pipeline information.

Use code to achieve auto increase.

Use [Definitions - Update REST AP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0)I to change the pipeline definition(variables of the pipeline.).

Comment: This is a ton of work to accomplish what GitVersion does easily with a single command. Don't do this. Use GitVersion.

Comment: @DanielMann Hi Daniel, thanks for your reply, if possible, could you please share your solution when you are free if possible? I believe it will be helpful to others, thanks!

Comment: Hi @BowmanZhu-MSFT Thank you for the solution. Will check this and revert back.

Comment: Hi @DanielMann, I found that GitVersion is not supporting Linux build server as it does a windows build server. It is complicated for GitVersion to work on Linux build server. If i'm wrong in any way, please let me know if it works and i will go back and try again.

Comment: @deepak GitVersion works fine on Linux. If you're having difficulty, please ask a new question about it.